# Trouble integrating game centre on cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So i did go through raywenderlich website and got the game centre authentication happening but i cannot integrate it to post high score to my leaderboard.

Where do you specify your leaderboard ID and how do you submit a score on click of a menu item?

I looked everywhere and cannot find. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We used [this GCManager](https://github.com/e5faf2/GCManager/blob/master/GCManager) as the baseline for integrating GameCenter.

Search for saveAndReportScore in the GCManager.m file. The exact code that you should be looking at starts at line# 194.